# what is the diffent between useContext and Consumer?

Tags: reactjs

when i use React Context,that is difference between this two ways.

this is Provider

```
import { type } from "node:os";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export type ENV_TYPE = "dev" | "citest" | "gld" | "pre" | "prd" | string;
interface IUser {
  name: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;
}

export interface IDataContextState {
  env: ENV_TYPE;
  user: IUser[];
  onEnvChange: (env: ENV_TYPE) => void;
  onUserChange: (val: IUser[]) => void;
}
export const DataContext = React.createContext<IDataContextState>(
  {} as IDataContextState
);
const DataProvider = (props: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser[]>({} as IUser[]);
  const [env, setEnv] = useState<ENV_TYPE>("dev");
  const onEnvChange = (env: ENV_TYPE) => {
    setEnv(env);
    // TODO （设置当前ENV的User）
  };
  const onUserChange = (val: IUser[]) => {
    setUser(val);
  };

  return (
    <DataContext.Provider
      value={{ env: env, user: user, onEnvChange, onUserChange }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </DataContext.Provider>
  );
};
export { DataProvider };
```

1. Consumer

```
    <DataProvider>
      <DataContext.Consumer>
        {({ env, onEnvChange }) => (
          <>
            <p>当前环境：{env}</p>
            <div className="app">
              <Tabs type="card" onChange={onEnvChange}>
                {tabData.map(({ key }) => (
                  <TabPane tab={key} key={key}>
                    <Main />
                  </TabPane>
                ))}
              </Tabs>
            </div>
          </>
        )}
      </DataContext.Consumer>
    </DataProvider>
```

this ways `onChange` works well. But when use useContext

2. useContext

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import Main from "./components/main";
import { DataProvider, DataContext } from "./context";
import "./App.css";

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const {env,onEnvChange} = useContext(DataContext);
  const tabData = [
    {
      key: "dev",
    },
    {
      key: "citest",
    },
    {
      key: "gld",
    },
    {
      key: "pre",
    },
    {
      key: "prd",
    },
  ];
  const handleTabChange = (activeKey: string) => {
    onEnvChange(activeKey);
    console.log(activeKey);
  };
  return (
    <DataProvider>
      {/* <DataContext.Consumer>
        {({ env, onEnvChange }) => ( */}
          <>
            <p>当前环境：{env}</p>
            <div className="app">
              <Tabs type="card" onChange={handleTabChange}>
                {tabData.map(({ key }) => (
                  <TabPane tab={key} key={key}>
                    <Main />
                  </TabPane>
                ))}
              </Tabs>
            </div>
          </>
        {/* // )} */}
      {/* </DataContext.Consumer> */}
    </DataProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

that `Uncaught TypeError: onEnvChange is not a function`

it is my fault?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using useContext outside your DataProvider

```
<App>
   useContext
   <DataProvider> </DataProvider>
</App>
```

You need to use useContext inside your DataProivder to get the context

```
<DataProvider>
   <App>
        useContext
  </App>
</DataProvider>
```

Comment: <App> is always inside < DataProivder>

Comment: i try check <DataProvider> outside of <App> it works well,But why i works well when use Consumer?

Comment: consumer or useContext both need to be inside your provider. Look at your Consumer. It's inside DataProvider. With your useContext, you use it in App where DataProvider is also rendered there.

Answer (score 0):

`<App>` component is outside of `Datacontext`.
Try this:

```
<DataProvider>
  <App />
</DataProvider>
```